# Volumetric Light not rendering volume correctly

Tags: opengl, glsl, lighting

I've been following this tutorial (https://www.programmersought.com/article/68075912719/) to get volumetric light. But I am not getting the correct output.

[image]

[image]

The shadow volume is incorrectly rendered and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. My vertex and fragment shader looks exactly like the tutorial but still I'm not getting correct output.

Here is the vertex shader code

```
#version 450 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 texCoord;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 normal;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 vp;

uniform float zFar;
uniform float fov;;
uniform float aspectRatio;

out vec2 TexCoord;
out vec2 farPlanePos;

void main(void){

gl_Position =  vec4(position, 1.0);

TexCoord = vec2 (texCoord.x, 1 - texCoord.y);

float t = tan(fov/2);
farPlanePos.x = (TexCoord.x * 2 - 1) * zFar * t * aspectRatio;
farPlanePos.y = (TexCoord.y * 2 - 1) * zFar * t;

}
```

And Here is the fragment shader code

#version 450 core

```
in vec2 TexCoord;


uniform vec3 cameraPos;
uniform vec3 lightPos;
uniform vec3 lightColor;

uniform mat4 invViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 invProjectionMatrix;

uniform float ambientStrength;

uniform sampler2D gPosition;
uniform sampler2D gNormal;
uniform sampler2D gAlbedoSpec;
uniform sampler2D gDepth;

uniform sampler2D shadowMapTexture;


in vec2 farPlanePos;

uniform float zFar;
uniform float zNear;


float g = 0.0f;




uniform mat4 lightViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

uniform mat4 viewMatrix;


vec3 yellow_light = vec3(1,198.0/255.0,107.0/255.0);

out vec4 finalColor;

// use linear z depth
vec3 ComputeWorldPos(float depth){

vec4 pos = vec4(vec3(farPlanePos.x, farPlanePos.y, -zFar) * depth , 1.0f);
vec4 ret = invViewMatrix * pos;
return ret.xyz / ret.w;    
}


bool IsInShadow(vec4 worldPos){

float fShadow = 0.0;
vec4 lightPos = (lightViewMatrix * (worldPos));
float fDistance = -lightPos.z / zFar;

lightPos = projectionMatrix * lightPos;

vec2 uv = lightPos.xy / lightPos.w * 0.5 + vec2(0.5f, 0.5f);

uv.x = clamp(uv.x, 0.0f, 1.0f);
uv.y = clamp(uv.y, 0.0f, 1.0f);

float offset = 0.5f/zFar;

float distanceMap = texture2D(shadowMapTexture, uv).r;
return fDistance - offset > distanceMap;
}

void main(void){

 float depth = texture2D(gDepth, TexCoord).w;

 vec3 total_light;

// volume light
{
    float I = 0.0f;
    float d = depth * zFar;
    int virtual_plane_num = 100;
    int begin = int(virtual_plane_num * zNear / (d - zNear));
    int end = int(virtual_plane_num * (zFar - d) / (d - zNear));
    for(int j = begin; j <= virtual_plane_num + begin; j++)
    {
        float z = 1.0f * j / (begin + virtual_plane_num + end);

        vec3 pos = ComputeWorldPos(z);

        if(z < depth && !IsInShadow(vec4(pos,1.0f)))
        {
            //vec3 lightDis = pos - lightPos;
            //vec3 viewDis = pos - cameraPos;

            //float lightDis2 = lightDis.x * lightDis.x + lightDis.y * lightDis.y  + lightDis.z * lightDis.z;

            vec3 lightDir = normalize(pos - lightPos);
            vec3 viewDir = normalize(pos - cameraPos);

            float cosTheta = dot(lightDir,normalize(-lightPos));

            float hg = 1.0f/(4.0f*3.14f)* (1.0f - g*g)/ pow(1.0f + g * g - 2.0f * g * dot(lightDir,-viewDir), 1.5f);
            
            if(cosTheta >0.9){
                I += clamp(10 * hg / virtual_plane_num, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            }
        }        
    }

    I = clamp(I , 0.0f,1.0f);
    total_light += I * yellow_light;

}


    vec3 normal =   texture2D(gNormal, TexCoord).xyz * 2 - 1; //result.xyz * 2 - 1;
    vec3 worldPos = ComputeWorldPos(depth);


// parallel lights
/*
{
    vec3 ViewDir = normalize( cameraPos - worldPos );
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(vec3(0.5,1,0.2) );
    vec3 halfDir = normalize(lightDir + ViewDir);
    float diffuse = 0.3 * clamp(dot(normal, lightDir), 0, 1) ;
    vec3 reflectDir = normalize(reflect(-lightDir,normal));
    float specular =  0.3 * pow(clamp(dot(reflectDir,halfDir),0,1),50.0);
    vec3 color = (diffuse + specular) *vec3(1,1,1);
    total_light += color;
}
*/

vec3 color = vec3(texture2D(gAlbedoSpec,TexCoord));
float ambient = 0.1;

finalColor = vec4(total_light + ambient * color,1);
}
```

So you can see the vertex and fragment shader code is exactly like the blog, but still the output is different.

Unfortunately it doesn't say how to contact the blogger otherwise I would have asked them directly. So the next best option is stockoverflow, so I am asking here.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after 2 days I was able to fix the issue. I think the isInShadow function is incorrect as it always perspective divies by zFar and also doesnt multiply by projection matrix before getting current depth.

So I replaced the code with learnOpengl shadow calculation as below.

```
bool IsInShadow(vec4 worldPos){


vec4 lightPos = (lightViewMatrix * (worldPos));

//float fDistance = -lightPos.z/ zFar;

lightPos = projectionMatrix * lightPos;

vec3 projCoords = lightPos.xyz / lightPos.w ;

projCoords = projCoords* 0.5 + 0.5f;

//uv.x = clamp(uv.x, 0.0f, 1.0f);
//uv.y = clamp(uv.y, 0.0f, 1.0f);

float offset = 0.5f/zFar;

float distanceMap = texture2D(shadowMapTexture, projCoords.xy).r;
return projCoords.z - offset > distanceMap;

}
```

And now the code works!!

[image]